# GPML returns a negative predictive probability. Why?

Tags: regression, machine-learning, matlab, gaussian-process

I'm using GPML (Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning) v3.2 in Matlab.

```
meanfunc = @meanConst; hyp.mean = 0;
covfunc = @covSEard; ell = 1.0; sf = 1.0; hyp.cov = log([ell*ones(1,size(xtr,2)) sf]);
likfunc = @likGauss; sn = .1; hyp.lik = log(sn);
inffunc = @infLOO;
hyp = minimize(hyp, @gp, -4*40, inffunc, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, xtr, ytr);
[myte vyte mfte vfte lp] = gp(hyp, inffunc, meanfunc, covfunc, likfunc, xtr, ytr, xte, yte);
```

`exp(lp)` has values greater than 1 (e.g., 1.1254).

Why?

Answer (score 3):

This is a big aha moment when going from discrete to continuous random variables.

Probability densities in continuous spaces can be greater than 1. The restriction that they should be below 1 is only for discrete random variables.

For continuous random variables the integral of the density has to be one:

$$\int_xp(x)dx = 1,$$

Thus, a uniform distribution over the interval $[0, 0.1]$ has to have a probability density of $p(x) = 10$ everywhere. It is only intervals (and their sums) which will always be less than 1.

Comment: It's _densities_ that can be greater than 1, which is your main point. It is never true that probabilities can exceed 1, so the answer needs editing.

Comment: Well, I know that DENSITY could be > 1, but it's the PROBABILITY which is > 1 in this case. So the question stands.

Comment: No. Check the book/docs/math, it is the value of a probability density function. (It is confusing, since Rasmussen's bookand the GPML package use the word probability as loosely as I did in my first answer.)